# Функция на С для PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql

Я написал функцию на С для PostgreSQL и начинаю собирать под систему с разной разрядностью (х86, х64). ОС - Windows 10. Вот краткий код

```
#include"postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif


PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one);

PGDLLEXPORT 
Datum add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{...}
```

Когда я собираю для x86 у меня все проходит успешно. Когда я собираю для x64 появляется ошибка `add_one redefinition; different linkage`.

Для ликвидации этой ошибки я делаю так (данный код компилируется успешно и для х86)

```
#include"postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PGDLLEXPORT Datum add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one);

Datum add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{...}
```

Если я поменяю порядок строк:

```
 PGDLLEXPORT Datum add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
 PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one);
```

На такой:

```
 PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one);
 PGDLLEXPORT Datum add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
```

То появляется та же ошибка.

Первый вопрос: почему для х86 платформы компилируется хорошо, а для х64 необходимо внести такие изменения.

Второй вопрос: если данный код я попробую собрать под Linux, мне нужно ли будет вносить изменения в сам код, так как `PGDLLEXPORT` это макроопределение для экспорта в винде.

Пишу в MSVC2017.

Comment: Как именно собираете? Ошибка именно при компиляции? В доке не описаны особенности сборки под windows: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html И проблема явно с этим, макрос `PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1` сам проставляет `PGDLLEXPORT`: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/include/fmgr.h#L373 Но подробнее я ответить не смогу, платформой windows не пользуюсь

Answer (score 0):

Макрос `PGDLLEXPORT` работает только под Windows (см. [src/include/port/win32.h](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c2c69d43addb23cde95eb428ef85902d52529251/src/include/port/win32.h#L89)):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define PGDLLEXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define PGDLLEXPORT
#endif
#else                           /* not CYGWIN, not MSVC, not MingW */
#define PGDLLIMPORT
#define PGDLLEXPORT
#endif
```

так что вреда при сборке под Linux он не принесёт.

Но вообще, если пишите кроссплатформенный код, то логичнее всего экспорт в MSVC сделать через *.def файл, а строку `PGDLLEXPORT Datum add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);` из исходников вообще убрать.

Comment: В дополнение, длинное обсуждение на [pgsql-hackers](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B539300BD%40ntex2010a.host.magwien.gv.at) на тему того, что не так с `PGDLLEXPORT` и что сделать, чтобы пример из документации работал и под MSVC.